# Vuejs axios delete method works in created but not in methods

Tags: express, axios, vuex

when I execute this in created, it works:

```
axios
  .delete('http://localhost:8000/product/10')
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

however, if I make a button and on submit I call a method that executes the same code it doesn't work, in the back, I get in the console

```
OPTIONS /product/10 204 0.172 ms - 0
```

Note that when I press the button the page refreshes and if I click the button several times fast it executes

Edit: I disabled the refresh, and now it works, Is there anything I can do because I want the method to execute even if I refresh.
the template:

```
<b-form class="mt-5 pt-5">
  <b-form-group id="productId" label="Product id " label-form="productIdInput">
    <b-form-input id="productIdInput" type="text" v-model="productForm.id" placeholder="enter product id you wish to delete"> </b-form-input>
  </b-form-group>
  <button type="button" v-on:click="deleteProduct()">Delete</button>
</b-form>

methods:{
  deleteProduct() {
    // this.$store.dispatch('removeProduct',this.productForm.id);
    axios
      .delete('http://localhost:8000/product/10')
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      })
  },
}
```

Comment: can you post your method?

Comment: there you go, as i said it's the same, it worked in created, but when i used in methods , it didn't so the problem which i hardly figured was due to the page refreshing.(still i don't understand why the request doesn't fully continue when there is a refresh

Comment: have you tried adding e.preventDefault() in method that you are calling on click? (Passing e as param to function)

Comment: because default behavior of form submit is to refresh

Comment: I tried it, and it worked thaanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The delete request sends options first it seems due to cross-origin and then it waits for response to send the real request, when i click a button and the page refreshes the options is sent, however (what i understood) is that the delete request no longer exists to wait for the response, so simply i added a e.preventDefault() in the method